# folium choropleth returns blank

Tags: folium

I have a GeoDataFrame that plots nicely from Geopandas, but returns blank as Choropleth graph in Folium.

Folium 0.7.0
Geopandas 0.5.0

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.rcParams['figure.figsize'] = [12, 12] 
radiosambab.plot('situacionpromedio', antialiased=False)
```

[image]

As a geojson

```
radiosambab.__geo_interface__
```

returns

```
{'type': 'FeatureCollection',
 'features': [{'id': '020130302',
   'type': 'Feature',
   'properties': {'situacionpromedio': 1.1173449839705998},
   'geometry': {'type': 'Polygon',
    'coordinates': (((-58.46738862003677, -34.53484761336359),
      (-58.466080612615286, -34.53427219003239),
      (-58.46379657486779, -34.53326322986549),
      (-58.46165233386257, -34.530802575280035),
      (-58.46133757821172, -34.530441540420355),
      (-58.4588949370924, -34.527620828300144),
      (-58.45884013885469, -34.52762641175383),
      (-58.45875915687486, -34.527621382400326),
      (-58.458732162886044, -34.52761970593736),
      (-58.45867655438868, -34.52763422563783),
      (-58.45856182767256, -34.52767203362345),
      (-58.45850001004012, -34.52769515425145),
      (-58.458440891778, -34.52771844249678),
      (-58.45839257108904, -34.52774240132773),
      (-58.45834357673059, -34.5277438516926),
...
```

Calling
`radiosambab['situacionpromedio']`
returns a Geoseries as expected:

```
COD_2010
020130302    1.117345
020131101    1.117371
020130104    1.161630
020130102    1.087263
020130101    1.268362
020120405    1.132843
020130107    1.085900
020130106    1.028195
020130109    1.056225
020130111    1.061627
020120407    1.138702
020120404    1.084368
020120402    1.078862
...
```

But, when invoking folium.Choropleth, it does not work:

```
m_2 = folium.Map(location=[-34.603722, -58.381592], tiles='openstreetmap', zoom_start=14)
folium.Choropleth(geo_data=radiosambab.__geo_interface__, data=radiosambab['situacionpromedio'], key_on='feature.id', fill_color='YlOrBr').add_to(m_2)
folium.LayerControl().add_to(m_2)
m_2
```

Returns

[image]

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Problem seems to be related to lack of memory. Is actually plotting when restricting the number of polygons. But fails to do so above 2000 polygons aprox.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem and solved it with:

var_geodataframe = var_geodataframe.to_crs(epsg=4326)

May be must use the actual version of folium and review the [Geopandas](https://geopandas.org/en/stable/gallery/polygon_plotting_with_folium.html).